# Is there a data structure where using bottom is needed to have a correct type?

Tags: haskell, types

Is there a type in Haskell where is absolutely needed to use bottom value i.e. `undefined`? Or it is just used to get the code compiling while the code is in process?

I thought maybe exist a rare type  that needs `undefined` to finish its construction, lists needs only `1:[]` and that's it, but maybe a data type is complex enough to need undefined` to finish its construction.

Is there more complex constructor that need `undefined` to be typed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question yet. Is your question whether there is any type for which any term that has that type is bottom? Or are you asking whether there is any type where idiomatic use of that type involves a bottom somewhere? Or something else...?

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks a lot! with you questions I could find some really nice info.

Comment: [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562652/how-to-delete-an-element-from-a-leafy-binary-tree-haskell) what looks like one example. :) empty tree would be `empty = Node 0 undefined undefined`. (Of course one could put anything there, including `empty` or `Node 10000000 empty empty`; it's not a good design.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, you want to pass a value just to pass the type of that value, while you don't care about the actual value. Take for example `asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a`. It does not examine is seconds argument, it's just there to set the type `a`:

```
Prelude> maxBound `asTypeOf` (0::Word)
18446744073709551615
Prelude> maxBound `asTypeOf` (0::Int)
9223372036854775807
Prelude> maxBound `asTypeOf` (undefined::Int)
9223372036854775807
```

As you see, `asTypeOf` works perfectly with `undefined` being passed as value for its second argument, because *any* `Int`-typed value will cause `maxBound` to be taken as `maxBound` for `Int`.

You might argue that it is a stupid idea to pass a *value* to `asTypeOf` which you never use. That type feels wrong. Instead, you just need to pass *something* carrying the type information. There are implementations of a `Proxy` type using that idea, although the standard version of `Proxy` is slightly different. A simple `Proxy` implementation could work like this:

```
-- Note: No data constructor at all.
-- This type is uninhabitated, the only possible value is undefined
data Proxy a

-- generator function for a proxy value. As there is no value, it has to return
-- undefined.
proxy :: Proxy a
proxy = undefined

asProxiedBy :: a -> Proxy a -> a
asProxiedBy x _ = x
```

With this code, you can write

```
*Main> maxBound `asProxiedBy` (proxy :: Proxy Int)
9223372036854775807
```

In this revised example, replace `asTypeOf` by `asProxiedBy`, you no longer pass an unused value, but instead you passed the undefined value as reference type. To avoid to spell the ugly word `undefined`, the method `proxy` has been introduced to generate `undefined` values of all `Proxy` types.

Comment: Yeah, but you really *shouldn't* use that sort of proxy, because it makes you use `undefined`!

Comment: The usual definition of proxies has `data Proxy a = Proxy`. The whole point of the pattern is to use `Proxy` -- a fully-defined value -- instead of `undefined`, thus making it possible to entirely avoid needing `undefined`.

Comment: In modern Haskell, I believe there's little need for `asTypeOf`, if any. Writing `x :: T` is now always possible thanks to `ScopedTypeVariables`, and that documents the intended type better than ``x `asTypeOf` y``, where you need `y` to be of the intended type. We never had to use ``x `asTypeOf` (undefined :: T)` since that would be equivalent to `x :: T`, we needed `asTypeOf` when we could not write `T` explicitly, but we had a value of that type at hand, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found some examples where undefined can fit:

```
newtype Wrap = W {w :: Wrap} deriving Show

www = W $ W $ W $ undefined
```

and you can count them (with no end):

```
count :: Wrap -> Int
count (W a) = count a + 1
```

Here, `Wrap` needs `undefined` to end.

```
class Peano a where
    zero :: a
    next :: a -> a


alt_zero, alt_one, alt_two, alt_three :: (Peano a) => a
alt_zero = undefined
alt_one = next alt_zero -- = succ undefined
alt_two = next alt_one -- = succ (succ undefined)
alt_three = next alt_two -- = succ (succ (succ undefined))
```

here you can create 1, 2, 3 without instance, or you can give a concrete type also.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving Show

instance (Peano Nat) where
  zero = Z
  next = S

instance (Peano Wrap) where
  zero = undefined
  next = W

countN :: Nat -> Int 
countN Z = 0
countN (S n) = (countN n) + 1
```

And some implementations. I knew if I search a little more I would find something

Comment: Or `data Void = Void !Void`, or if you don't care about Haskell 98, `data Void`. But these are boring. There are much more interesting uses of bottom out there. Look at the definition I wrote for `Data.Sequence.zipWith`.

Comment: @dfeuer indeed there are! l = Seq $ Deep 3 (One (Elem (1,2))) EmptyT (Two undefined (Elem (5,6)))

Comment: `Wrap` does not need `undefined` to end: `x = W x` is not bottom (and does not contain bottom anywhere inside). Perhaps you intended it to be a `newtype` instead?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner indeed, you are right like always :). Isn’t that the same as ‘n = n + 1’?

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero It is not the same: `(+)` is not a data constructor, but `W` is.

Comment: @DanielWagner but at least similar? W is a function, also a data constructor. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DanielWagner one last question, how would you define `zero` in Peano for Wrap without undefined?

Comment: Yes, `W` is a function. But data constructors are special: they mark places where evaluation to WHNF is permitted to stop. Mere non-constructor function applications do not share this property. See also "guarded recursion"; `x = W x` is guarded, while `x = 1 + x` is not.

Comment: As for your question about `zero`, I am skeptical that your `instance Peano Wrap` as written here is sensible. Because you have switched to a newtype, It is not possible to distinguish `zero :: Wrap` and `next zero :: Wrap` -- they are both bottom.